# Turn a written month into a number mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this structure in mysql:

```
+----+---------------+------+
| ID | DATE          | WHAT |
+----+---------------+------+
| 1  | GENNAIO 2020  | 1    |
+----+---------------+------+
| 2  | FEBBRAIO 2021 | 2    |
+----+---------------+------+
| 3  | GENNAIO 2020  | 1    |
+----+---------------+------+
```

I should be able to sort it by date, unfortunately being written in letters I don't know how to proceed.
I emphasize that I cannot use the id because the entry could be different from the written date.

PS. The months are written in Italian (January, February)

The complete answer from suggest of @Tim Biegeleisen

```
SELECT `ID`,`DATE`,CASE 
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%GENNAIO%' THEN   CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','01','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%FEBBRAIO%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','02','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%MARZO%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','03','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%APRILE%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','04','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%MAGGIO%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','05','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%GIUGNO%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','06','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%LUGLIO%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','07','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%AGOSTO%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','08','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%SETTEMBRE%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','09','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%OTTOBRE%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','10','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%NOVEMBRE%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','11','-10')
              WHEN `DATE` LIKE '%DICEMBRE%' THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DATE`, ' ', -1),'-','12','-10')
              END AS DATAA
FROM `mytable` order by DATAA DESC
```

I added %MONTHS% to find the month and I added the quotes for the month so that November and December also work.
Obviously as pointed out in the comments below it is always better to use a date in number, in fact I will use this query to transform the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression here:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    DATE,
    CASE WHEN DATE LIKE 'GENNAIO' THEN 1
         WHEN DATE LIKE 'FEBBRAIO' THEN 2
         ... END AS MONTH
FROM yourTable;
```

A better way to handle this would be to use `STR_TO_DATE`, and convert the text dates to bona fide dates, then extract the numeric month.  This assumes that `STR_TO_DATE` on your MySQL would have locale support for Italian.  But an even *better* approach would be to stop storing your dates as text.  Just use a bona fide date column and avoid these problems.

Comment: And it is actually like that for everything else, unfortunately for this part it still uses an antiquated method. So do you think it would be better to spend time tweaking everything?

Comment: If by "tweaking" you mean getting proper dates to avoid verbose `CASE` expressions, then yes, I recommend it.

Comment: I will probably modify the whole system. for now in the meantime that I fix things by trying to use the first way I can get the number in the month, but how can I also take the year? ps. I also added `%value%`

Comment: In this particular case, to get the string year, you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(DATE, ' ', -1)`

Answer (score 2):

Simpler than a `CASE` expression is `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT id, 
       FIND_IN_SET(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ' ', 1),
         'GENNAIO,FEBBRAIO,MARZO,APRILE,MAGGIO,GIUGNO,LUGLIO,AGOSTO,SETTEMBRE,OTTOBRE,NOVEMBRE,DICEMBRE'
       ) month,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ' ', -1) year
FROM mytable
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=740e9d2435fe3868e3fd9cd8c83bca45).
Results:

```
> id | month | year
> -: | ----: | :---
>  1 |     1 | 2020
>  2 |     2 | 2020
>  3 |     1 | 2020
```

Comment: That work too, thanks for your time but i will change method for better approach